# Unable to install libgit2 library on AMI ec2 instance

Tags: r, linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, libgit2

I am trying to install devtools in a R ami on an amazon ec2 instance. However, before devtools, I need to install some variation of a libgit2 library as a dependency. Given that the amazon distro is red hat, I've tried to install the libgit2-devel variation with the command

```
sudo yum install libgit2-devel
```

everytime i get a error message that the package is not available. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the exact same problem right now